# Flutter TextField add box shadow

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, uitextfield, flutter-layout

I tried create `TextField` with shadow effect using `Container` like this:

[image]

**Code:**

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.black12,
        spreadRadius: 1,
        blurRadius: 3,
      ),
    ],
  ),
  child: TextFormField(
    validator: (value) {
      if (value.isEmpty) {
        return 'Product title required';
      }
      return null;
    },
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      isDense: true,
      hintText: 'Product title',
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
      filled: true,
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
      ),
    ),
    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
    maxLines: 1,
  ),
)
```

But when validation has error then error message shows inside `Container` which is incorrect in my case:

[image]

How I can create `TextField` like this shadow with correctly displaying error message and error border colors like this but with shadow:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try to wrap it with "Material" widget

```
Material(
 elevation: 5,
 child: TextFormField(
    validator: (value) {
      if (value.isEmpty) {
        return 'Product title required';
      }
      return null;
    },
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      isDense: true,
      hintText: 'Product title',
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
      filled: true,
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
      ),
    ),
    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
    maxLines: 1,
  ),
),
```